# What does uniqueness mean in the NoSQL world, how do I handle relations in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I am currently trying to figure out, how Nosql databases handle relations and what the unique Id of a Document really means.

Maybe I am expecting too much of MongoDb or I haven't grasp the concept of relations in NoSQL databases yet.

Basically, the following test fails, and I wonder how one would model such a relation between Users and Groups (which is a 1 : 0..N relation).

```
[TestFixture]
public class MongoDbExamples
{

    private MongoServer _mongoServer;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureSetUp()
    {
        _mongoServer = MongoServer.Create();
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void FixtureTearDown()
    {
        _mongoServer.Disconnect();
    }


    [Test]
    public void RelationTest()
    {
        var database = _mongoServer.GetDatabase("StackoverflowExamples");

        var p = new Person() { Name = "Testperson" };
        var persons = database.GetCollection<Person>("Persons");
        persons.Save<Person>(p);

        var group = new Group() { Description = "A fancy descriptor" };
        group.Add(p);
        var groups = database.GetCollection<Group>("Groups");
        groups.Save<Group>(group);

        var readPerson = persons.FindOneById(p.Id);
        readPerson.Name = "a different name";
        // since the id hasn't change this is an update of the original person:
        persons.Insert<Person>(readPerson);

        // and I thought that it should be reflected in the group as well:
        var readGroup = groups.FindOneById(group.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(readPerson.Id, readGroup.persons[0].Id); // this passes, the id is the same
        Assert.AreEqual(readPerson.Name, readGroup.persons[0].Name); // this fails, the groups person still has the old name
    }

}
```

Are there best practices for such relations? E.g. Should search for all person in all Collections/Documents and exchange those found with the matching person of the persons collection? Or are relations something which NoSQL databases aren't good at and I should avoid relations (I wonder how to use a NoSQL-DB in a bigger system with more complex object graphs then)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as relations or auto-updates of related collections. Seems like you expect mongo to behave like an ORM, but that is not what it does, at least not with the C# driver. If you want to save a Person and a Group you will have to save them both individually.

Rather than storing full person objects inside the group objects, you should store just the person ids instead. Then use those Ids to do a lookup of the person when you need the person data.

Also, you may wan to read the docs on dbref.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef

Comment: +1 for the link. I think I finally understood the concept of NoSQL Databases. Also the DBRef keyword seems to be what I need ("
Use the DBRef class. It takes the collection name and _id as parameters to the constructor. Then you can use the FollowReference method on the Database class to get the referenced document.") for Read purposes, and I need to manually update the entities as Andrew Orsich pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

First of all there are no relations and joins in mongodb. All 'relations' are logical, but it not real relation like in sql database. In test above you storing person twice: first person goes into persons collection, second i guess goes into nested collection of persons within group.

You just duplicated person. So, they are not related. And if person was updated in persons collection it does not mean that he will magically updated in nested collection of persons within group collection. This is the reason why your test fails.

Usual one to many relation in mongodb good fit for embedding.

**Update:**
I guess you have documents like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
    }

    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
        persons = new List<Person>();
    }

    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Person> persons { get; set; }

    public void Add(Person p)
    {
        persons.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Also i a little modified your test to get it work:

```
var database = _mongoServer.GetDatabase("StackoverflowExamples");

var p = new Person() { Name = "Testperson" };
var persons = database.GetCollection<Person>("Persons");
persons.Save<Person>(p);

var group = new Group() { Description = "A fancy descriptor" };
group.Add(p);
var groups = database.GetCollection<Group>("Groups");
groups.Save<Group>(group);

//Groups collection
//{
//  "_id": "4da54d3c00a9ec06a0067456",
//  "Description": "A fancy descriptor",
//  "persons": [
//    {
//      "_id": "4da54d3b00a9ec06a0067455",
//      "Name": "Testperson"
//    }
//  ]
//}

//Persons collection
//{
//  "_id": "4da54d3b00a9ec06a0067455",
//  "Name": "Testperson"
//}


var readPerson = persons.FindOneById(p.Id);
readPerson.Name = "a different name";
//Here i've changed Insert to Save
persons.Save(readPerson);

//Here you updating person in persons collection, 
//but within group name still old

//Persons collection
//{
//  "_id": "4da54d3b00a9ec06a0067455",
//  "Name": "a different name"
//}

//So to achieve 'physical relation' you need also update person within group
var query = Query.EQ("persons._id", readPerson.Id);
groups.Update(query, Update.Set("persons.$.Name", readPerson.Name));

//Groups collection
//{
//  "_id": "4da54d3c00a9ec06a0067456",
//  "Description": "A fancy descriptor",
//  "persons": [
//    {
//      "_id": "4da54d3b00a9ec06a0067455",
//      "Name": "a different name"
//    }
//  ]
//}


//Test passed
var readGroup = groups.FindOneById(group.Id);
Assert.AreEqual(readPerson.Id, readGroup.persons[0].Id); 
Assert.AreEqual(readPerson.Name, readGroup.persons[0].Name);
```

Comment: How can I achieve a kind of "physical relation" then? In this example, do I have to persist persons in a collection and embedded in within group collection and after reading, search for the person and exchange it manually?

Comment: (+1) Thanks Andrew for clarifying the update procedure. However, the link sym3tri and Hightechrider provided finally made me understand.

Answer (score 3):

There's no uniqueness on Name unless you created a unique index on it. (see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-UniqueIndexes)

You used **Insert** instead of **Update** or **Save** so it's going to create a new document for you.

Comment: Even if I am using save, there are still two different persons with the same ID: one in the person collection, one embedded in the group. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do (have a "globally unique" person which is only referenced not necessarly embedded in other documents)? I don't understand the unique indexes, can you please provide a working example (e.g. modify my code above)?

Comment: Take a look at this page too: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References